# iPhone OS 4.x - background TCP sockets are not responding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multitasking

I'm trying to implement the background mode for VoIP application using the new mechanisms provided by iPhone OS 4.x

Still without success... Application remains silent in the background mode when some data arrives from the server via TCP socket.

According to the documentation the following two things have to be done:

1. Add `voip` value for `Required background modes` in `Info.plst` file
2. Set property `kCFStreamNetworkServiceType` of `CFReadStreamRef` object to `kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP` value

I'm using an externally created BSD socket to instantiate `CFReadStreamRef` with `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket` function. Socket handle is correct - checked with some testing. So I'm obtaining a correct `CFReadStreamRef` object, which I'm later configuring and opening.

Here is the chunk of code:

```
CFSocketNativeHandle socket = (CFSocketNativeHandle)socketHandle; 
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket(kCFAllocatorDefault, socket, &sipSocketReadStream, nil);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(sipSocketReadStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
NSInputStream *inputStream = (NSInputStream*)sipSocketReadStream;   
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
CFReadStreamOpen(sipSocketReadStream);
```

Please note - my delegate for `NSInputStream` receives successfully `Stream Opened` event. But any other events simply didn't come - I was expecting to receive an event when some TCP traffic started to arrive.

Answer (score 4):

I must reiterate the sage advice mentioned by Gilad. The background TCP sockets do **NOT** work on the Simulator. I spent quite a while trying to get to the bottom of this problem, sucked in by the convenience of the Simulator.

In addition, and maybe its just me, I didn't find it clear from the documentation which value was the key and which value was the property. For the record, this is how I set it and it works:

```
res = [oStream setProperty:NSStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP 
                    forKey:NSStreamNetworkServiceType];

if(!res){
   // Error handling here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have `UIBackgroundModes` as an array, with the `voip` option in your plist file:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

In addition, `voip` background tasks do **NOT** work under the simulator, so make sure you test with a real device. If you did set the `UIBackgroundModes` properly and set the stream type to `kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP`, then my only conclusion is that you are probably testing with the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you missing **[inputStream open]** .Once open the stream i hope you get call on your delegate method .

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent
```

After successful TCP connection on VOIP mode only the iOS keep your socket alive even app on background mode.